# Are there any primary sources discussing the feeling of being near Shekhinah in the Holy Temple?

Tags: sources-mekorot, beis-hamikdash, ruach-hakodesh

I think that maybe [Philo of Alexandria](https://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/12116-philo-judaeus) was one, but that's just a guess from me, and I don't think his writings are that direct. I'm essentially looking for a first-hand extra-Tanakhic source of someone who felt the Shekhinah in or near the Holy Temple.

Comment: According to the Zohar, Avraham avinu saw the shechinah accompanying Sarah (Lech Lecha 12).

Comment: @Shmuel Zohar however, was written down well over a millenia after the Second Holy Temple. I was looking for more first hand accounts - e.g. Philo I'm pretty sure directly visited the Second Holy Temple.